# Index tables in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing

I would like to know how to open a index table in SQLite ?
Can I read the content in the index table ?

Comment: What are you trying to _do_? Reading an index directly doesn't give you anything useable unless you're writing the database engine itself.

Comment: I think you have your terminology confused. You can create a table, and then you can create an index on that table. You never choose to read the index directly though; you just read the table. The SQLite engine then uses the indexes you have created to optimise your queries.